# Merge two Arraylist & retains all the value in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have 2 `arrayList` of `PresentErrorList` & `PastErrorList` both having 3 fields `errorCode`,`presentErrorCount` & `pastErrorCount` .

**presentErrorList**

```
[errorCode=1000,presentErrorCount=10,pastErrorCount =0]
[errorCode=1100,presentErrorCount=2,pastErrorCount =0]
```

**pastErrorList**

```
[errorCode=1003,presentErrorCount=0,pastErrorCount =10]
[errorCode=1104,presentErrorCount=0,pastErrorCount =12]
[errorCode=1000,presentErrorCount=0,pastErrorCount =12]
```

While calculating for Present, pastErrorCount =0 and viceversa . My finalArrayList should be

```
[errorCode=1000,presentErrorCount=10,**pastErrorCount =12**]
[errorCode=1100,presentErrorCount=2,pastErrorCount =0]
[errorCode=1003,presentErrorCount=0,pastErrorCount =10]
[errorCode=1104,presentErrorCount=0,pastErrorCount =12]`
```

As you can see in the final list for `errorCode=1000` as it is duplicate in past so there will be only 1 object with both present & past error count .

Comment: Please give the code of ArrayList, i can help

Comment: Am just getting value from DB filtering based on creation_date separating it to present & past errorList . Is the above result possible in final ArrayList?

Comment: hi @azro Do you got any idea?How to proceed?

Comment: what is the type of `List<>`-between the `<>` ? so you have a class representing what's inside, can you give the definition ? ( attrbutes)

Comment: List<ErrorCodeModel> which has 3 attributes as given above .

Comment: I was thinking of another approach of using a Map<String, List<ErrorCodeModel>> key will be errorCode & value will be  lists of all rows from 2 lists but the blocker here is if same errorCode exist in 2 list how to replace the '0' with actual number . I want to show it in a table format of ErrorCode,PresentErrorCode & PastErrorCode as column .

Comment: the 3 are `int` type I suppose ?

Comment: ErrorCode is String rest are int .

Comment: Done ;) I hope you'll find it great :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there was not easy to find a way but a the end that's what I do :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ErrorCodeModel> presentErrorList = new ArrayList<>();
    presentErrorList.add(new ErrorCodeModel("1000", 10, 0));
    presentErrorList.add(new ErrorCodeModel("1100", 2, 0));

    List<ErrorCodeModel> pastErrorList = new ArrayList<>();
    pastErrorList.add(new ErrorCodeModel("1003", 0, 10));
    pastErrorList.add(new ErrorCodeModel("1104", 0, 12));
    pastErrorList.add(new ErrorCodeModel("1000", 0, 12));

    Map<String, ErrorCodeModel> map = Stream.of(presentErrorList, pastErrorList)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(ErrorCodeModel::getErrorCode,
                      Function.identity(),
                      (oldValue, newValue)
                      -> new ErrorCodeModel(oldValue.getErrorCode(),
                           oldValue.getPresentErrorCount()+newValue.getPresentErrorCount(),
                           oldValue.getPastErrorCount()+newValue.getPastErrorCount())));

    List<ErrorCodeModel> errorList = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

    errorList.sort((err1, err2) //line 20*
                -> Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(err1.getErrorCode()),
                                   Integer.parseInt(err2.getErrorCode())));

    System.out.println(errorList.toString());

    //*line 20 : Optionnal, if you want to sort by errorCode
    //(need to parse to int to avoir alphabetical order
}
```

So after add your elements, this is what is done :

- A stream of each 2 `List` is done
- the goal is to add them in a `Map` :  (object's code, object)
- the (oldValue,newValue) lambda-exp is used is the `key` is always in the map, I tell it to add a new Object which has the sum of previous and the new to add
- after the map, a `List` is generated from the `values` which represents the ErrorCodeModel as you ask

Comment: Hi @arzon thanx alot for the solution but can you convert it to Java7 am not much confident on Java8 unable to understand the solutions .Again it would greatly help Thanx alot again.

Comment: Hi @arzon thnx buddy i figure it out to convert .

Comment: Streams are a feature of java 8, it would be possible in java 7 but much more bad to do , so i won't because I've answered, and you may accept to evolve with features and not stay in the past, and I see no reason to not be "confident" with Java8 ... ^^

Comment: Yes as u said in java 7 its messy i have no other option as our whole product code in java7 only . So have to do with it .